# Can't boot WEBrick, the folder for Rails gem is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, railstutorial.org, webrick

I'm following Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), and I got stuck at trying to start rails server on my Windows 7 machine.

I'm trying to do this by following instructions in [Chapter 1.2.5.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-rails_server), i.e. by typing

```
rails server
```

However, instead of booting WEBrick, this returns the instructions for usage of 'rails' command. I've been googling this for a while, and some of the answers seem to have implied that something is wrong with the rails gem.

Now, I've found the rails gem folder ("C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rails-3.2.3"), and it's empty!

Also when I try

```
rails -v
```

it returns "Rails 3.2.16", although I've removed this version of the gem; if I try

```
gem list
```

it kept telling me that the version is 3.2.3.

This persisted until I deleted railties version 3.2.16, which resulted in

```
rails -v
```

returning 'Rails 3.2.3', but I still can't boot WEBrick.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to run `rails server` from the Rails project folder. Did you `CD` into that?

Comment: Hi @Arup, yes I'm running 'rails server' command from my project folder.

Comment: Weird... I've just uninstalled everything, deleted all the files and directories, and installed a fresh ROR using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/). The folder for Rails 3.2.16 gem is still empty...

Comment: are you using RVM to manage your gems and rubby versions?

Comment: Hi @toolz, I'm not using RVM as I'm on Win7; however, I did install Pik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've managed to solve my problem.

I've seen a few more people having the same issue, but none of the solutions that I've found helped me, so here's what did it for me, though I'm not 100% sure what exactly was that one thing that actually did it...

I've followed the advice @scarver2 gave in response to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830622/im-confused-rails-v-and-gem-list-show-different-versions), and uninstalled both `Rails` and `Railties` gems from my crispy fresh installation of Ruby 1.9.3. (I've installed it using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)). Then I've installed `Rails 3.2.16` gem by typing

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.16
```

and this also installed the corresponding `Railties 3.2.16` gem without my intervention.

Then I followed steps from chapters 1.2.3. and 1.2.5. of the tutorial, but making sure that line referencing `ruby` version in my `Gemfile` actually corresponds to the version of Ruby that I have installed.

I typed

```
ruby -v
```

in the console, to make sure that I have version 1.9.3. indeed. Confirming this, I've edited the `Gemfile` in my app so it says

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

instead of `ruby '2.0.0'` line that's used in Listing 1.5. of the tutorial.

After that I've simply went to my app folder, and typed

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

in the console, and this time it did not return any errors as it did in my previous attempts. After that, typing

```
rails server
```

did what it should have, and my WEBrick server booted, allowing me to access my app on localhost. Yay!

Now, what I think may have gone wrong the last time was either me screwing up the `Gemfile`, so the gem versions and their dependencies got messed up. I also assume that ineptly trying to fix this by installing and uninstalling different versions of various gems did not quite help. What may have helped was uninstalling `Rails` and `Railties` gems, and installing `Rails` gem again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the installer?

At the time of this writing, I recommend using the `Ruby 2.0.0-p353`.
http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p353.exe?direct
Save yourself some future gem headaches and install the DevKit too. 
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

It should create a folder at `C:\Ruby200`. Start a new command prompt for the new paths to take affect.

Once Ruby is install, gem install Rails. From your other post, I recommend `gem install rails -v 3.2.16`

Then execute `rails new project_name`, then `cd project_name`. Then run `rake db:migrate` to create the initial database. At this point, you should be able to run `rails server` and visit `localhost:3000` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks @scarver2! I didn't need to follow your advice, as I managed to solve my problem by other means, but I think you did help me; pls see my own answer below.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Thank you for sharing a detailed solution. Thanks for the credit in you responses.