# I'm confused: 'rails -v' and 'gem list' show different versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, windows-7-x64, webrick

I've made a fresh installation of Ruby on Rails on my Windows 7 machine (using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/)) after a failed attempt to follow Michael Hartl's  [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) (if you're interested, see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829330/cant-boot-webrick-the-folder-for-rails-gem-is-empty) pertaining to the said fail).

As I thought my previous fail had something to do with my inept attempt at installing different gem versions hoping to replicate requirements laid out in the tutorial, I decided to check the version of rails gem immediately after the install.

When I typed

```
rails -v
```

I got `Rails 4.0.2` as a response, but when I did

```
gem list
```

it said `rails (3.2.16)`, and that got me really confused.

Are we talking about two different things here?

Mind you that this is a crisp install: these two commands were the first, and the only two commands I ever typed.

Can this be the reason I [couldn't boot WEBrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829330/cant-boot-webrick-the-folder-for-rails-gem-is-empty) for my sample project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is the `Railties` executable wrapper is still installed. You need to uninstall the `Rails` gem *and* and the `Railties` gem.

```
$ gem uninstall rails
$ gem uninstall railties
```

You will likely be prompted to select which version of the gem to uninstall.

If needed, you can reinstall a specific version of Rails.

```
$ gem install rails -v 3.2.16
$ gem install railties -v 3.2.16
```

Comment: Brilliant, got it: `Rails` and `Railties` are mutually dependent. I did as you said, and now I have just Rails 3.2.16 showing on both `rails -v` and `gem list`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

gem list will show all gems you've installed.  If you have multiple versions of rails installed it will show them.

Comment: Thanks @toolz, I knew that, but the problem was that `gem list` showed just `rails (3.2.16)`, but as @scarver2 explained above, the different messages were due to later version of `Railties` being installed as well...